# jQuery AddClass/RemoveClass/Attr Isn't Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

There is a nearby location on the property listing page. I want to show is collapsed on the page load.
I tried add/removeclass and attr but didn't work.

Theme dynamically removes "`in`" to `collapseFive` class + "`collapsed`" to `panel-title` class

Original code, not collapsed

```
<div class="panel-wrapper yelp_wrapper">
                <a class="panel-title" id="yelp_details" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#yelp_details" href="#collapseFive"><span class="panel-title-arrow"></span>Yakınlarda Neler Var</a>
                <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
```

Original code, collapsed

```
<div class="panel-wrapper yelp_wrapper">
                <a class="panel-title collapsed" id="yelp_details" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#yelp_details" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false"><span class="panel-title-arrow"></span>Yakınlarda Neler Var</a>
                <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 0px;">
```

Add class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#yelp_details").addClass("collapsed");
});
```

Remove class

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#collapseFive").removeClass("in");
});
```

Attr

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#collapseFive").attr("class", "panel-collapse collapse");
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this is a boostrap collapse. If that's right, you need to use:

> [.collapse('show')](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/javascript/#collapse-methods): hows a collapsible element.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="panel-wrapper yelp_wrapper">
    <a class="panel-title" id="yelp_details" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#yelp_details"
       href="#collapseFive"><span class="panel-title-arrow"></span>Yakınlarda Neler Var</a>

<script>
  $(function () {
      $('#collapseFive').collapse('show');
  });
</script>

    <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="well">
            1
            2
            3
            4
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but on js fiddle works, on the site don't work. i couldn't find why. http://jsfiddle.net/tosunkaya/nc0vxzj7/1/
site: https://villadoktor.com/ilan/villa-7-yildiz-guney/

Comment: @emretosunkaya snippet updated. Copy and paste exactly the content of snippet....

Comment: is it related with version, on bootstrap 3.3 isn't working.

Comment: Thanks for your help now it's collapsed on page load. It's related with jquery version, on jquery 1.12.4 wasn't working. I updated to 2.2.4 (latest one before jquery 3) now works.